# Can a wizard have previously prepared objects as backup arcane focuses?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, spellcasting-focus

Could a wizard somehow have already prepped objects (like backup wands, staves, or whatever object) as backup arcane focuses?

For example, say you're a [Runesage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo-wizard-archetypes/runesage-wizard-archetype/) (which is the class I'm interested in), and it tells you to treat your floating rock similar to an arcane focus when switching the school it channels (i.e. inscribing a new rune into it). Can I prepare 4 extra shiny gems with the other school's runes on each one, having paid the costs for them already, and then switch out which rune I have prepped each morning?

Comment: Hi ThreeQuent, welcome to RPG StackExchange! I've changed some of the wording in your post and title to make some aspects clearer; feel free to edit it back if you wish, or clarify other parts of it.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately you can generally only have one Arcane Bond at a time.

From [Runic Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo-wizard-archetypes/runesage-wizard-archetype/):

> While the first runic focus a runesage creates is free, replacement runic foci can be created using the standard rules for replacing a bonded object for a wizard’s arcane bond.

From [Arcane Bond](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/#TOC-Arcane-Bond-Ex-or-Sp-):

> If the object of an arcane bond is lost or destroyed, it can be replaced after 1 week in a special ritual that costs 200 gp per wizard level plus the cost of the masterwork item.

These options are only available when the first foci is lost or destroyed. No other options for creating such bonds is provided.

Further reinforcing this is the final text from Runic Focus:

> For example, a runesage with a runic focus on necromancy could abandon that focus and replace it with a new focus on any school other than abjuration and enchantment (as these two schools are opposition schools to Sin necromancy).

Abandons is a permanent thing - this is not putting it in your pocket for later.